Sign in and Sign up with username instead of Email address in Entra External ID
I'm new to Entra External ID.
Exploring the feasibility of implementing username-based Sign In/Up functionality instead of email-based. Seeking guidance on potential custom extensions to accommodate this change. Limited online resources available for specific implementation details.

Currently, this is not supported, although it is on the road map.
There are no extensions that would achieve this.

Do you have any info when will it be generally available?

No firm date - no.

Is it possible to determine the quarter and year? Thank you for your patience.

No - I just know it's on the roadmap.
